# Getting more information about Gradle build error

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a hybrid mobile app that uses Ionic Framework 5.x and while it builds with no issues, when I run the command `ionic capacitor update` and try to run the app using Android Studio 4.1.1 and Gradle 3.6.1 (`android/capacitor/build.gradle`), the app does not get installed in the Android emulator (I am testing on Android 7), due to the following error:

`Gradle build failed with 1 error(s) in 1 s 532 ms`

Is there a way I can find out what the error is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build manually:

```
cd ./android/capacitor
./gradlew :assembleDebug
```

Comment: I was able to get the build error using your solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can check `Logcat` or `Event Log`